# Can we Use Codeception for app developed in php 4.4

Tags: php, behat, codeception

**Background**

We are planning to migrate our organization client facing application from php4.4 to php5.3 or higher.

**Problem:**

Based on suggestion from the book "Working-Effectively-with-Legacy-Code" we are planning to create first behavior test cases using *behat* or *codeception* slowly and when we have most of the critical pieces covered with test cases we thought of going for migration. So now we are evaluating behat and codeception to do the job.

We would like to know whether codeception can be used for the php4.4 sites also? Based on this we want to use Codeception over behat. Any Suggestions related to this is very helpful for us to take decision.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: this question is not suitable for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Codeception can test sites on different PHP versions and not only PHP
But you need PHP 5.4 in CLI to execute Codeception.

You should install different version of PHPs for webserver and for your CLI in order to do so.  You can use phpenv or phpbrew to have multiple PHPs installed. Just switch to 4.4. for webserver and 5.4 for CLI.

Then you may write Codeception acceptance tests using PhpBrowser or Selenium WebDriver